# Rails building a Serialized object of N records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to serialize any object(s) in text columns.

Via an API, I get the params:

```
params[:attachments] -- this can be 0 or 1 or 3, or 100+ etc...
params[:attachment1]...params[:attachment2] ... params[:attachmentN]
```

So how do I store X # of attachments in a serialized object?

mailThing = MailThing.create(:attachments => myAttachmentsSerizliedIfANY )

I'm trying to do:

```
@myAttachmentsSerizliedIfANY = nil

i = 0
attachmentCount = params[:attachments].to_i
while i < attachmentCount do

   @myAttachmentsSerizliedIfANY << params[:attachment + i ]

   i += 1
end
```

Any suggestions on how to get this working? thanks

Comment: Can you give a little more information?  What type of database column do you have?  What type of data is in the attachments?

Comment: they can be any type of email attachments. database column can be whatever it needs to be... text or blob

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so I looked at some of your other questions, and I think I might have something that will work for you.  For this to work, you will need to have a column in the database (I'll call it `attachment_storage`) where you can store these attachments after you serialize them.

Basically you want to get the attachments into an array first, and then serialize it into a string so that you can store it into the database.

Here's some code to get that done.

```
attachment_storage = []
(1..params[:attachments].to_i).each do |attachment_num|
   attachment_storage << params["attachment#{attachment_num}".to_sym]
end
```

Here we're building the symbols for the params hash using the string and to_sym to turn it into a symbol like `:attachment1`, `:attachment2`, etc.

Then you want to put in the database, so you can store it as noted in the [ActiveRecord Documentation][1] under the section "Saving arrays, hashes, and other non-mappable objects in text columns".

In order for the serialization to work, you need to add `serialize :attachment_storage` to your model, and then to store it you would assign it just like any other parameter as above.  Then save your model and it will be serialized for you.

Comment: Thanks! I can't wait to try this. Right now I'm also trying to figure out how to get the rest of the Mail object into the db. New question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870184/rails-storing-a-actionmail-mail-new-object-in-the-database   after I solve for that I'll jump into this. thanks

Comment: What should the column type be for

Comment: What should the column type be for attachment storage

Comment: Jamuraa, thanks for this. I was able to tweak it to store the binary of the file ( i think) by doing:     attachment_storage = []
    (1..params[:attachments].to_i).each do |attachment_num|
      attachment_storage << open(params["attachment#{attachment_num}".to_sym].tempfile.path) {|f| f.read }
    end    
Problem is I am unable to read that later in delayed job. ideas on how to read what's stored in the db?