# Rails - Storing a ActionMail Mail.new object in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I'm creating a mail object like so:

```
 textpart_to_inject= params[:text]
 htmlpart_to_inject= params[:html]

  message_all = Mail.new do
    to #{params[:to]}
    from #{params[:from]}
    subject #{params[:subject]}
    text_part do
      body textpart_to_inject
    end
    html_part do
      content_type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
      body  htmlpart_to_inject
    end
  end
```

I then want to insert that into the database like so:

```
@incoming_mail = IncomingMail.create(:message_all => Base64.encode64(message_all), :message_plain => Base64.encode64(params[:text]))
```

But that errors with:

```
TypeError (can't convert Mail::Message into String):
  app/controllers/incoming_mails_controller.rb:56:in `create'
```

My database columns are as follows:
    message_all = bytea
    message_plain = text

Ideas? thanks

Comment: So, you are trying to store the entire Mail object into the database as bytes?

Comment: If possible that would be fantastic!!! any way to do that? I don't know about the bytes part but I do want the Mail object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at Rails's `serialize` method?  It sounds like that's exactly what you want to do.  See the docs [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-serialize) (also check out the section about 1/6 from the top under the heading "Saving arrays, hashes, and other non-mappable objects in text columns").  It might even be as simple as adding

```
serialize :message_all
serialize :message_plain
```

to your IncomingMail model, but don't take my word on that.

Your error, by the way, is coming up because `Base64.encode64()` only works on strings.

Hope this helps!